# How to modify Tomcat setenv.sh to set GC arguments based on Java major version?

Tags: batch-file, tomcat, sh

I'm trying to modify Tomcat to load a specific set of GC arguments depending on the Java version installed.

This is what I've done for setenv.bat:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms400m -Xmx1g "-Djava.library.path=%LOCALLIBPATH%" -Dderby.system.home=db -Dam.ehcache.set_rmi_ip_addr=true -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M -XX:NewSize=128M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=logs -Dhost.name=%COMPUTERNAME% -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=conf/amtrust.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=passphrase

:setGC
rem determine the Java major version first, then add the GC args accordingly
set "_JAVACMD=%JAVACMD%"
if "%_JAVACMD"=="" (
  if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" (
    if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set "_JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
  )
)
if "%_JAVACMD%"=="" set _JAVACMD=java
set JAVA_VERSION=0
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('%_JAVACMD% -Xms32M -Xmx32M -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
  set JAVA_VERSION=%%g
)
set JAVA_VERSION=%JAVA_VERSION:"=%
for /f "delims=.-_ tokens=1-2" %%v in ("%JAVA_VERSION%") do (
  if /I "%%v" EQU "1" (
    set JAVA_VERSION=%%w
  ) else (
    set JAVA_VERSION=%%v
  )
)
if /I "%JAVA_VERSION%" GTR 8 (
  set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Xlog:gc*:file=logs/%COMPUTERNAME%_gc.log
) else (
  set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Xloggc:logs/%COMPUTERNAME%_gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails
)
```

I'd like to do the same for setenv.sh, but I'm not familiar with shell scripting, and the tutorials I found online are all using bash scripting.